# javac doesn't see class in package

Tags: java, class, package, javac

my folder with all classes my program needs looks like this

[first image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lDuj.png)

[second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WnINF.png)

The program successfully runs in Intellij idea Embedded Local Terminal but it isn't running in command prompt(cmd).

I run my program in cmd like this

> C:\Users\misha\IdeaProjects\Elib\src>javac -cp . myTask\Main.java

But it just creates .class files.

[my directory after running my program in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUhc6.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command `javac` compiles the file(s) you specify. After (successful) compilation, you are able to run the compiled files. Simply after compiling run `java` command on your public class that contains the `main` method.

Comment: Thank you very much!!!The solution is so simple that now I feel kinda dumb xD

Comment: No problem, we're all here to help. If the answer helped you, consider accepting it (by clicking the tick below the score), so that future visitors can see that this answer solved the problem